# Modify JavaFX Application scene from different thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, user-interface, javafx, concurrency

I've added a gui to my client application, 
and trying to forward the socket messages to it. 
I mocked the client to be a singleton until now, 
so I could access it from the `Application` thread, 
but now I want multiple clients to access their gui. 
I know `fxml` has bound property listeners but 
I want it as simply as possible. 
To work directly with the threads themselves. 
How would I make `Platform.runLater()` reference the 
scene instance if `Application.launch()` constructs its own? 
I've read quite extensively but solutions everywhere 
turn out to leverage an `fxml` interface skipping the work which I wouldn't like. 
Control class (simplified, issue on line 9):

```
public class Client {
    private Socket socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1",4444);
    private BufferedReader incoming = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
    private Browser browser = new Browser();
    public static void main(String[] arguments) throws IOException {
        Application.launch(browser.class);
        while(socket.isConnected()) {
            Platform.runLater(new Runnable(){
                @Override public void run(){
                    try{browser.bubble(incoming.readLine());}
                    catch(IOException fail){fail.printStackTrace();}
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

User interface (simplified):

```
public class Browser extends Application {
    private Stage stage;
    private Scene scene;
    private BorderPane layout = new BorderPane();
    private VBox history = new VBox();
    @Override public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        layout.setCenter(history);
        scene = new Scene(layout);
        stage = stage;
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
    public void bubble(String message){
        VBox record = new VBox();
        Label label = new Label(message);
        record.getChildren().add(label);
        history.getChildren().add(record);
    }
}
```

Comment: In the vast majority of cases, you shouldn't be calling `Application.launch()` from anywhere except a main method, and shouldn't be doing anything else in the main method. Do this the other way around; I.e. create your `Client` instance from your `start()` method and call the method containing the code you posted from there (in a background thread). You still have threading issues - you are blocking the fx Application thread with the `readLine()` call.

Comment: Yeah sorry I missed to include the psvm method, corrected. I like the principles You draw, nothing else in the main method and instantiating from the Application... Dispatching that instance to a third thread could solve the blocking issue as well couldnt it... I'm probably gonna go down this way.

Answer (score 2):

You should only ever have one instance of your `Application` subclass, which is the instance created when the application is launched via `Application.launch()`. Your `main()` method in a JavaFX Application should really only call `Application.launch()` and do nothing else; you should consider the `start()` (or `init()`) method(s) that are invoked as part of the launch process to be the entry point for the application.

Consequently, you should create the `Client` instance from the `start()` method, and set it doing what it does in a background thread.

You can achieve all this by refactoring your code as follows:

```
public class Browser extends Application {
    private Stage stage;
    private Scene scene;
    private BorderPane layout = new BorderPane();
    private VBox history = new VBox();
    @Override public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        layout.setCenter(history);
        scene = new Scene(layout);
        stage = stage;
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

        Client client = new Client(this);
        Thread thread = new Thread(client::processIncomingData);
        thread.setDaemon(true);
        thread.start();
    }
    public void bubble(String message){
        VBox record = new VBox();
        Label label = new Label(message);
        record.getChildren().add(label);
        history.getChildren().add(record);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }
}
```

and

```
public class Client {
    private Socket socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1",4444);
    private BufferedReader incoming = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
    private Browser browser ;

    public Client(Browser browser) {
        this.browser = browser ;
    }

    public void processIncomingData()  {
        while(socket.isConnected()) {
            try {
                String data = incoming.readLine();
                Platform.runLater(() -> browser.bubble(data));
            } catch (IOException exc) {
                // TODO: handle properly
                exc.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

A couple of other things to note: `Application.launch()` blocks until the application exits; so in your original code your `while` loop wouldn't even start until the application was closing down. Also, the `readLine()` method blocks, so you don't want to do that on the FX Application Thread (it will prevent the UI from responding in any way until a line is read). The latter issue is fixed by moving `readLine()` out of the `Platform.runLater()` block.

Comment: Alright so I reversed the logic and instantiated from the Application thread. It's nice enough. Inserting `Application.launch()` before the loop was just a mistake in my shortening but great to mention. Thank you, James.